# Light per vertex shader

Tags: glsl, shader

I´m trying to compile this glsl shader but looks like has something wrong, because he fails. This is the message error the _log gaves me: Vertex shader(s) were not successfully compiled before glLinkProgram()was called.Link failed.

Its a light per vertex shader:

```
  vec4 ambient()
    {
        vec4 ambient = vec4 (0.0);
        ambient = gl_FrontMaterial.ambient * gl_LightSource[0].ambient;
        ambient += (gl_LightModel.ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient);
        return ambient;

    }

    vec4 diffuse(vec3 normal)
    {

        vec3 diffuse  = gl_LightSource[0].position * normal;

        float diff = max(dot(normal,diffuse),0.0);
        diffuse = gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * diff;
        return diffuse;
    }

    vec4 specular(vec3 normal)
    {
        float hv = max(dot(normal, vec3(gl_LightSource[0].halfVector)), 0.0);

        float spec = pow(hv, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);

        return gl_LightSource[0].specular * gl_FrontMaterial.specular * spec;
    }

    void main()
    {

        vec3 normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);   

        vec4 ambient = ambient();
        vec4 diffuse = diffuse(normal);
        vec4 specular = specular(normal);

        gl_FrontColor = gl_Color*(ambient+difuse)+specular;


        gl_Position = ftransform();

    }
```

this is the shader class:

```
#include "Shader.h"
namespace topicos
{

#include "Shader.h"

Shader::Shader()
{
    program = glCreateProgram();
}

Shader::~Shader()
{

    glDetachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glDetachShader(program, geometryShader);
    glDetachShader(program, fragmentShader);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(geometryShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    glDeleteProgram(program);
}

void Shader::determinarFontes(std::string vertex, std::string geometry, std::string fragment)
{

    vertexFileName = vertex;
    geometryFileName = geometry;
    fragmentFileName = fragment;
}

void Shader::ativarShader()
{
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glUseProgram(program);
    programLog(program);
    shaderLog(program);

    std::cout<<_log;


}

void Shader::desativarShader()
{

    glUseProgram(0);
}

void Shader::shaderLog(unsigned int obj)
{

    int infologLength = 0;
    int charsWritten  = 0;
    char *infoLog;

    glGetShaderiv(obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infologLength);

    if (infologLength > 0)
    {
        infoLog = new char[infologLength];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(obj, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog);

        std::string str(infoLog);

        if (!str.empty())
        {
            _log += "\n" + str;
        }
        else
        {
            _log += "Done.\n";
        }

        delete [] infoLog;
    }
}

void Shader::programLog(unsigned int obj)
{

    int infologLength = 0;
    int charsWritten  = 0;
    char *infoLog;

    glGetProgramiv(obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infologLength);

    if (infologLength > 0)
    {
        infoLog = new char[infologLength];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(obj, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog);

        std::string str(infoLog);

        if (!str.empty())
        {
            _log += "\n" + str;
        }
        else
        {
            _log += "Done.\n";
        }

        delete [] infoLog;
    }
}
std::string Shader::loadShader(std::string shaderFile)
{

    std::string texto = "";

    std::ifstream obj;
    obj.open(shaderFile.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);

   // std::cout << " ..>> " << obj.is_open() << std::endl;

    std::string linha;

    while(std::getline(obj, linha))
    {
        texto +=  linha + "\n";
    }
    obj.close();
//std::cout<<"texto: " << texto<< std::endl;
    return texto;
}
void Shader::makeVertexShader(const std::string& vertexFileName)
{
    /**This function creates a vertex shader,
    compiles it and attached to the program**/
    const char *stringConvertidaVertex = loadShader(vertexFileName).c_str();
    //std::cout<<"vertex shader: " << loadShader(vertexFileName)<<std::endl;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &stringConvertidaVertex, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
}
void Shader::makeFragmentShader(const std::string& fragmentFileName)
{
    /**This function creates a fragment shader,
    compiles it and attached to the program**/
    const char *stringConvertidaFragment = loadShader(fragmentFileName).c_str();
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &stringConvertidaFragment, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
}
void Shader::makeGeometryShader(const std::string& geometryFileName)
{
    /**This function creates a fragment shader,
    compiles it and attached to the program**/
    const char *stringConvertidaGeometry = loadShader(geometryFileName).c_str();
    geometryShader = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(geometryShader, 1, &stringConvertidaGeometry, NULL);
    glCompileShader(geometryShader);
    glAttachShader(program, geometryShader);
}

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include the full compile error message in your question?

Comment: Vertex shader(s) were not successfully compiled before glLinkProgram()was called.Link failed.

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24425436/906839) recent answer useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved
This is the correct light per vertex shader:

```
vec4 ambient()
{
    vec4 ambient = vec4 (0.0);
    ambient = gl_FrontMaterial.ambient * gl_LightSource[0].ambient;
    ambient += (gl_LightModel.ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient);
    return ambient;
}

vec4 diffuse(vec3 normal)
{
    vec4 diffuse=(0,0);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position));
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    diffuse = gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * diff;
    return diffuse;
}
vec4 specular(vec3 normal)
{
    float hv = max(dot(normal, vec3(gl_LightSource[0].halfVector.xyz)), 0.0);
    float spec = pow(hv, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);
    return gl_LightSource[0].specular * gl_FrontMaterial.specular * spec;
}
void main()
{
    vec3 normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);   
   vec4 ambient = ambient();
   vec4 diffuse = diffuse(normal);
   vec4 specular = specular(normal);
    gl_FrontColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;

    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A missing version number, mismatched dimensions and a typo.
(*I keep comments about coding style to myself.*)

```
#version 140 // ? I dislike guessing

vec4 ambient()
{
    vec4 ambient = vec4 (0.0);
    ambient = gl_FrontMaterial.ambient * gl_LightSource[0].ambient;
    ambient += (gl_LightModel.ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient);
    return ambient;

}

vec4 diffuse(vec3 normal)
{

    // vec3 diffuse  = gl_LightSource[0].position * normal;
    vec4 diffuse  = vec4(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz * normal,1.0);

    float diff = max(dot(normal,diffuse.xyz),0.0);
    diffuse = gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * diff;
    return diffuse;
}

vec4 specular(vec3 normal)
{
    float hv = max(dot(normal, vec3(gl_LightSource[0].halfVector)), 0.0);

    float spec = pow(hv, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);

    return gl_LightSource[0].specular * gl_FrontMaterial.specular * spec;
}

void main()
{

    vec3 normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);   

    vec4 ambient = ambient();
    vec4 diffuse = diffuse(normal);
    vec4 specular = specular(normal);

    // gl_FrontColor = gl_Color*(ambient+difuse)+specular;
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color*(ambient+diffuse)+specular;


    gl_Position = ftransform();

}
```

**ADDENDUM**

glslangValidator from http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/

foo.vert with above code

```
glslangValidator foo.vert 
echo $? 
0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but still not compile

Comment: Oh yes it does; see addendum above.

Comment: And what´s the difference this compiler for my? 
In my codeblocks project doesn't compile.

Comment: You wanted your vertex shader bugfixed, not your "project"., whatever the latter may denote.

Comment: But of course, I tested another shader and it works.I wan´t to understand what are the errors.

Comment: Then **show** us the errors. What you quoted is mangled log message from a program linker log, not from an original shader compiler log, as I've have told you already.

Comment: My professor send me a message with the following errors:
0:13(52): error: vector size mismatch for arithmetic operator
0:16(10): error: value of type vec4 cannot be assigned to variable of type vec3
0:17(16): error: `return' with wrong type vec3, in function `diffuse' returning vec4
0:38(42): error: `difuse' undeclared
0:38(42): error: operands to arithmetic operators must be numeric
0:38(43): error: operands to arithmetic operators must be numeric
0:38(52): error: operands to arithmetic operators must be numeric
 –

Comment: That are the errors in **your original source**; they are corrected in the source I returned to you. And in general - homework assignments do have a purpose. You, as a beginner, shall learn how to program. And programming requires bug-fixing and proof-reading skills.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
gl_FrontColor = gl_Color*(ambient+difuse)+specular;
```

should be

```
gl_FrontColor = gl_Color*(ambient+diffuse)+specular;
```

To let the driver display these errors so that you don't have to find them yourself, do this (it's in C, I'm not sure what host language you are using)

```c
// Checks if compilation of a shader was successful.
// On success, returns GL_TRUE. On failure, prints the
// error message to stderr and returns GL_FALSE. 
GLint check_shader_compilation_status(GLuint shader)
{
    GLchar* info_log;
    GLint r;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &r);
    if (r == GL_FALSE)
    {
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &r);
        info_log = malloc(sizeof(GLchar) * r);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, r, NULL, info_log);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", info_log);
        free(info_log);
        return GL_FALSE;
    }
    return GL_TRUE;
```

Comment: And when exactly do you intend to present that world-riddle solving, grand-unifying-theory founding, magic message to us? Just asking to make sure I'm dressed properly for that event.

Comment: What about reading the coments? I have already written the message: "Vertex shader(s) were not successfully compiled before glLinkProgram()was called.Link failed. "

Comment: That is not a message from glGetShaderInfoLog.

Comment: This "0:13(52): error: vector size mismatch for arithmetic operator 0:16(10): error: value of type vec4 cannot be assigned to variable of type vec3 0:17(16): error: return' with wrong type vec3, in function diffuse' returning vec4 [...]" is from glGetShaderInfoLog. This "Vertex shader(s) were not successfully compiled before glLinkProgram()was called.Link failed. " is not