# Vertex and Fragment shaders for lighting effect in OpenGL ES20

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I want to add a very simply lighting effect in my models via shaders. I found out there a vertex and a fragment shaders that make the work on OpenGL:

```
static const char* vertSource = {
    "uniform vec3 lightPosition;\n"
    "varying vec3 normal, eyeVec, lightDir;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vec4 vertexInEye = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;\n"
    "    eyeVec = -vertexInEye.xyz;\n"
    "    lightDir = vec3(lightPosition - vertexInEye.xyz);\n"
    "    normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;\n"
    "    gl_Position = ftransform();\n"
    "}\n"
};

static const char* fragSource = {
    "uniform vec4 lightDiffuse;\n"
    "uniform vec4 lightSpecular;\n"
    "uniform float shininess;\n"
    "varying vec3 normal, eyeVec, lightDir;\n"
    "void main (void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "  vec4 finalColor = gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor;\n"
    "  vec3 N = normalize(normal);\n"
    "  vec3 L = normalize(lightDir);\n"
    "  float lambert = dot(N,L);\n"
    "  if (lambert > 0.0)\n"
    "  {\n"
    "    finalColor += lightDiffuse * lambert;\n"
    "    vec3 E = normalize(eyeVec);\n"
    "    vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);\n"
    "    float specular = pow(max(dot(R, E), 0.0), shininess);\n"
    "    finalColor += lightSpecular * specular;\n"
    "  }\n"
    "  gl_FragColor = finalColor;\n"
    "}\n"
};
```

The problem is that I am working in OpenGL ES2, because I am developing an Android app. And it seems that the in-built variable gl_FrontLightModelProduct is not available for GLES20, because I am having compilation fails in this line.

My question therefore is: How I can modify the above shaders to make them work in a OpenGL ES20 context?

Comment: You will have to get rid of all the references to pre-defined state variables that were available in legacy OpenGL. It's very similar to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416589/glsl-using-custom-output-attribute-instead-of-gl-position. While that was about moving to the desktop core profile, what you need to do for OpenGL ES is very similar.

Comment: Very instructive your answer there. Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor` gives the Ambient colour of the scene which can be 0 if you want the area which is not affected by light to be fully black. You can replace that with a `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`

You should also remove these variables and send them as uniforms.

1. `gl_ModelViewMatrix` (send as uniform)
2. `gl_Vertex` (read this from attributes)
3. `gl_NormalMatrix` (send as uniform)
4. `gl_Normal` (read this from attributes)

Or instead of fighting in converting OpenGL shader, you can search for Simple OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders

Comment: I got exactly what I wanted just with your first suggestion, replacing gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor by vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0). So Thanks !!

I didn't have to remove gl_ModelViewMatrix and the others. Now I am curious, Why did it work?

Comment: Am not sure how it gets compiled, gl_ModelViewMatrix and other are not available in OpenGL ES 2.0. Probably it depends on the implementation. OR you are declaring and passing these uniforms with in your code somewhere.

Comment: Maybe is the implementation. As you can see from the shaders, they are not declared as uniforms